# property X does not exist on type Y

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting that error:

> Property 'module' does not exist on type 'Menu'.
>
> Property 'parentId' does not exist on type 'Menu'.

and code looks like this:

```
private menus: Menu[];


for (var i = 0; i < this.menus.length; i++) {
            if ((this.currRoute == "/" + this.ls.actLan + this.menus[i].module) && this.menus[i].parentId !== 0) {
                this.IsActive.emit(this.menus[i].parentId);
            } else {
                this.IsActive.emit(0);
            }
        }
```

**BUT** I have imported that ts file

```
import { Menu } from './menu';
```

and there I have these properties

```
export class Menu {
    constructor(
        id: number,
        type: number,
        module: any,
        urlType: string,
        url: string,
        name: string,
        parentId: any
    ) { }
}
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: None of the arguments in the `constructor` are declared either `private` or `public` and it basically does 
nothing. Either declare or assign, since right now the `Object` has no properties at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't have any properties on `Menu` class. You can automatically create properties from constructor arguments. See [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```
export class Menu {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public type: number,
        public module: any,
        public urlType: string,
        public url: string,
        public name: string,
        public parentId: any
    ) { }
}
```

Now all the parameters will also be public properties of `Menu`.

---

Or if you don't want to use parameter properties, you can define them one by one like this:

```
export class Menu {
    id: number;
    // ...
    constructor(id: number, type: number, module: any, url: string, name: string, parentId: any) {
        this.id = id;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this,

```
export class Menu {

    id: number;
    type: number;
    module: any;
    urlType: string;
    url: string;
    name: string;
    parentId: any;
    constructor(id: number, type: number, module: any, url: string, name: string, parentId: any) {
        this.id = id;
        this.module = module;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
}
```